# $$$, security concerns with using AppEngine in a client/server relationship with Android/iOS App

Tags: security, google-app-engine

I'm developing a smartphone app that, on the server side, sends User info (User password verification, this person has completed task X, uploaded YouTube video at link Y, belongs to group Z, has verified/unverified geographic location) to the server for storage.

My question is twofold: is the AppEngine is a good choice for this, considering a maximum potential of 1,000, rarely-concurrent-but-still-active users? My aim is to, at most, pay the $9/month fee, but all over the web are concerns about how easy it is to exceed this.

also, What security concerns do I need to address when transmitting data from the phone to the app, aside from using an https connection?

As an aside, I plan on using Go for the AppEngine portion.

Comment: may get a better response on programmers exchange

Answer (score 0):

The cost really depends on what your app is doing.

Google App Engine charges for most of the services. See the [quotas document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas) to see how much free quota you have with each service and additionally the Quota Details screen in the Administration Console.